# Dual boot on SSD - partitioning

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

I'm going to help a friend to build a new system with **only** a 500 Gb SSD and 8 Gb RAM and we want to install Windows 7 and Ubuntu LTS. The usage will be 95% Ubuntu and 5% Windows and the system will remain turned on for maaaany hours for website (**not** server) purposes. So please help me in these:

1. Is there a need to create a swap partition, as the memory is enough? If yes - how much?
2. Should I create manually a /boot partition?
3. Should I go for manually partitioning or with auto istallation alongside windows?

Please be free to suggest another solution or a new partitioning scheme.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If a new system, you may want to use UEFI, not the 35 year old BIOS/MBR. The Windows 7 DVD is BIOS only, but can be copied to a flash drive and some files moved around to make it UEFI bootable. How you boot install media, both Ubuntu & Windows is then how it installs. But you want both systems UEFI boot or both BIOS boot.

Comment: @oldfred -- FYI, 64-bit only images of Win7 were EFI compatible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to hibernate you need 10-12GB swap. If not, 2-4GB swap should be sufficient unless you do really heavy computing.

A separate `/boot` partition is unnecessary. Many users that use a separate `/boot` partition run into problems later as they make it way too small and run out of space after a couple of kernel updates.

Create an 80-100GB partition for the Windows install. If you want a shared data partition also make that and format it `ntfs`. Leave the rest of the drive unallocated. When installing Ubuntu choose "use unallocated space" and let the installer partition it.

Since you are using Windows 7, I assume you are installing in Legacy/CSM mode. In Legacy mode, it is very important to install Windows first then Ubuntu for the following reasons:

Windows does not see non-windows OSs so the bootloader will not auto configure to boot linux. And manual configuration is very difficult.

Both systems will write their bootloader to the MBR. So we want Ubuntu's bootloader (grub) in the MBR when we are finished, because grub can see and boot Windows.